# Sitecore: Where to plug in custom one time functionality?

Tags: timer, sitecore

I've been tasked with programmatically adding items into our Sitecore database at regular intervals, but have little to no experience using it. Using online resources, I have managed to find out how to programmatically create and add the new items to the database, after validating that the item does not already exist, but don't know where to add the code to the solution.

I was originally thinking of simply starting a timer and asynchronously running the code from the `Tick` event handler after each interval passes, but I'd need to setup the timer in a place in code that will only get hit once. I guess that Sitecore might also have a better way to achieve this.

I'd therefore appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction as to where to put the code and let me know if there is a better solution regarding performing an action at regular intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways you can achieve tasks that run at regular intervals. Depending on your requirements and what Sitecore offers, you should pick the one best for you. I have used the following tasks in the past. You can read about the tasks in more details provided by Sitecore Climber. The best one is John West's post.

- **Database embedded tasks (Scheduled Tasks)** - For this you have a to create a schedule item under /sitecore/system/Tasks/Schedules and a command item under /sitecore/system/Tasks/Commands. The command is where you specify a class and put in your custom logic. I like this approach since I can tell the start date, the end date, what days of a week and what time interval to run at. Also, this is relatively easy to turn on or off if you see any issues or don't need it anymore. To turn it on or off won't cause the app pool to recycle. The nice thing here is that the Schedule item contains a "Last Run' field which you can use as a parameter to tell your code to get items modified since the 'Last Run' date value. As a backup to this, I always write a page and put it in the /sitecore/admin folder in CM, that has controls for parameters as well as date to run this manually in case my server goes down and I need to run it manually. There is no exact timing this thing although you can get close.
- **Sitecore Agents** - Here what you can do is write a page and then specify that as a URL in the `<scheduling>` section of Sitecore config files. This is relatively straightforward since you write a page, place it in /Sitecore/admin folder and just call the URL. I think there might be some issues in the way query string parameters are handled by the `<scheduling>` section. You specify a time interval to run this at in the same place you specify the URL. This again is not exactly timed so it will never run at an exact time rather at regular intervals starting with when App pool starts. You will also have to implement your own way of storing 'Last Run' time here. Turning this on or off requires changes to a config file so app pool recycle will happen here.
- **Windows Task** - For cases where you need exact timing, this is the best option. You may have to write a web service for this. Also, you will need to to write your own 'Last Run' time logic. Turning this on or off is easy as going into the Windows Task console and disabling this.

With the first two options you need to make sure your Frequency element and agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent" method="Run" interval="00:10:00" name="Master_Database_Agent" patch:source="Sitecore.Processing.config" element to have time intervals less than the Schedule that you will create. This is covered in John West's blog in Sitecore Climber's answer.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your useful description of the alternative options.

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of task you need Sitecore Scheduled Task. 
You find more information how to create here: 
  https://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2014/08/09/scheduled-task-basics/

https://www.degdigital.com/insights/how-to-create-sitecore-scheduled-task/

http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2010/11/all-about-sitecore-scheduling-agents-and-tasks.aspx

https://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2015/09/17/one-more-way-to-run-sitecore-scheduled-task-at-the-same-time-every-day/

I also recommed this module:

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/S/Sitecron.aspx?sc_lang=en

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Unfortunately I can't set both answers as correct and @Gabbar's answer is more informative.